# Scrolling in div event listener not working pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, dom-events

My goal is for an image inside of a div to get smaller when you scroll down in that div. I made a working example of it in the body but not in a div.
https://jsfiddle.net/53u2e86m/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <img alt="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/LEGO_logo.svg/2000px-LEGO_logo.svg.png" id="logo">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!-- more brs ... -->
```

The CSS

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  transition: height .5s;
}
```

And the JS

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 25,
            logo = document.getElementById("logo");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            logo.style.height="150px";
        } else {
            if (distanceY < shrinkOn) {
                logo.style.height="300px";
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

Now I wanted to implement this in my project and I am using the mdl framework. The problem is that when I put this in the main div holder (the `<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">` one) the body doesn't scroll at all. The reason why is because the main mdl div is just as big as your screen and no bigger and its contents scroll. So I tried to set the scroll event listeners to the div but nothing worked. Here is my HTML:

```
   <!-- START OF MAIN DIV -->
    <div id="mainDiv" class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--no-desktop-drawer-button">

      <!-- header -->
      <div class="header"> 
        <img id="logo" src="pic/logo.png" alt="logo">

      </div>  

      <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--transparent ">
        <div class="mdl-layout-icon"></div>
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Comments</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Pictures</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Activities</a>
          </nav>
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout__title">Website</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Comments</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Pictures</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Activities</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!-- lots more <br> -->
    </div>
    <!-- END OF MAIN DIV -->
```

Here is my CSS

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  transition: height .5s;
}
```

And my JS

```
mainDiv.onload=function(){
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
function init() {
    mainDiv.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = mainDiv.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 25,
            logo = document.getElementById("logo");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            logo.style.height="150px";
        } else {
            if (distanceY < shrinkOn) {
                logo.style.height="300px";
            }
        }
    });
}
mainDiv.onload = init();


}
```

I just doesn't work and I get an error saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mainDiv is not defined(anonymous function) @ main.js:2

I've gotten very frustrated cause I've searched every where and I still can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: JSFiddle of the not working one https://jsfiddle.net/fe04kLf0/4/ .

Comment: You should really add the actual issue into a fiddle and verify that the issue is present; [read about that here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here's a [good starting point fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fe04kLf0/) for you to go and do that (MDL loaded).

Comment: try to declare the var main div as global variable.
You are creating that variable in the onload function but calling the variable before that function.
This var is private to the onload fn scope, thus , the scroll function will not know the variiable.

Comment: @ justinw I added a link. @ damiano celent Tried that but still no go. See the jsfiddle for example.

Comment: I just moved the link to the JS file to the bottom of my HTML document and I don't get any errors now but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried so hard to get it to work. Could someone please tell me how to set a scrolling event listener to a div instead of the body?